# Update credit card details of user for all subscriptions in Stripe using API

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I've created one user using the Stripe API and that customer is subscribed to 5 lessons. Now the user is wanted to change the credit card information. How can I update credit card details in all the subscriptions so that amount will be deducted from the new card using the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can first update the source(credit card) and then update the subscription of the user with the new Payment method.

**Steps:**

1. Update or add a new card (if user wants add a new card) - [Stripe Python Docs - Update card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/update)
2. After updating/adding the card details you can store the details in database and then update the subscription - [Stripe Python Docs - Update Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=python)

You can do this for all the subscriptions for a user, make sure you use proper fields available in the API for your use case.I assume, you would have all the subscription details of the user stored in the database, so you just need to fetch the subscription details and use the functions available in **stripe sdk**.

Comment: Thanks for replay @rajan-sharma I've tried that way but the card update API only allows me to update basic details like an address. I want to change the card numbers and CVV all that thing. How can I do the same?

Comment: ohh! In that case you can create a new card, add it as a default payment method for subscription and then delete the previous card from the customer's account.No standard app would let you modify the card number once you verify that with the customer.This would be the best way to achieve this in your usecase.

Comment: for more info on deleting cards refer  [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/delete?lang=python)

Comment: If that helps kindly upvote and mark it as correct! Happy coding :)